# Why is / taking up 7 GB of space (running `du`)?

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I am trying to determine what is taking so much disk space, so I run the following command:

```
du / -h -d 2 | sort -hr
```

which outputs the following

```
7.3G    /
5.1G    /var
3.8G    /var/www
1.1G    /usr
635M    /var/lib
573M    /var/cache
570M    /lib
474M    /lib/modules
354M    /usr/share
308M    /usr/src
262M    /usr/lib
135M    /usr/bin
118M    /var/log
```

What does the first line of output mean? why or how could `/` (nothing?) be taking up 7GB of space?

Comment: have you noticed if you add up all those values they equal 7.3G?

Comment: @TaylorBioniks of course you mean all of the *1 level deep* values.

Comment: To complement the answers, your error lies in *`/` (nothing?)*. In fact `/` contains *everything*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything you see is under `/` so its the sum up value of everything :P

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explain it in diagrammatically i should have explain like this i am sure that this diagram will help any one to understand the scenario.

Comment: Need to give image citation http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6666/1

Comment: Now I feel stupid, thank you for this, makes total sense.

Answer (score 4):

The numbers `du` gives are *[cumulative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cumulative)*. I.e. it's the space taken up by everything in the directory plus everything *underneath* the directory. The number for / therefore is how much space all the files on the filesystem are taking.

If you don't want cumulative numbers, you can use `du -S`.

Comment: Understood. I was basically looking to see which root folders had the most space. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @kisonay For that use Baobab or Filelight, two common disk usage analyzers (there are command line tools too).